# Почему выдает ошибку?

Tags: java

У меня есть абстрактный класс, у которого есть наследники. 
В наследниках считываю данные из внешних фалов в конструкторах классов - операция одинаковая для всех наследников. 
Решил реализовать считывание в классе родителе. В итоге получаю ошибку "NullPointerException"
Вот как это реализовано в родительском классе.

```
public abstract class Parent {

private ArrayList<Campaign> listOfCampaigns;
    private ArrayList<Campaign> filteredCampaigns;
    private String[] campaignsPath;

Parent(){
    super();
        listOfCampaigns = readListOfCampaigns(campaignsPath); // считывание 
}

public double find(Request request){

    // Первичная фильтрация
    filteredCampaigns = filterCampaigns(listOfCampaigns, request);

    return 1;

}

    protected ArrayList<Campaign> filterCampaigns (ArrayList<Campaign> totalListOfCampaigns, Request request){

    for ( int i = 0; i < totalListOfCampaigns.size(); i++ ){ // Вот и вылезает ошибка NullPointerException
            ...
            ...
            }
    }
}
```

Почему вылезает ошибка?

Comment: ну значит в totalListOfCampaigns ты нечего не передаешь

Comment: @Gorets: почему ничего? наверняка null :)

Comment: Почему же? я считываю данные в listOfCampaigns, а потом вызываю метод 
filterCampaigns в методе find, передав ему параметры listOfCampaigns, request

Comment: попробуйте в начале метода `filterCampaigns` написать

    if (totalListOfCampaigns == null) throw new Exception();

(временно, для отладки). Если вы и вправду не передаёте `null`, это не помешает.

Comment: Да тут ошибка даже еще раньше - пишет, что campaignsPath пустой

Comment: А он и вправду, похоже, пустой: вы ж не присваиваете ему ничего перед вызовом `readListOfCampaigns`.

Comment: Да, тут он пустой.
Но дальше, в наследниках у меня тоже есть поля campaignsPath.
И они там не пустые.

Просто в наследниках повторяется одна и та же операция считывания - вот и запихнул ее в родительский класс, в конструктор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` служит для вызова конструктора родительского класса, а вы вызываете метод для класса, у которого нет родителя. Опишите конструктор класса `parent`, потом в наследуемом обратитесь к нему внутри конструктора этого класса. Те `someClass(){super()}`

Comment: обычно jvm при компиляции сама создает пустой конструктор, если он не онаписан

Comment: Кстати, что значит у которого нет родителя? А Object?

Comment: @rasmisha тут имеется ввиду тот класс, который не имплементит никакой другой класс

Comment: Ну скорее "экстендит") А во вторых как раз от Object все классы без явно указанного родителя неявно наследуются.

Comment: ой, виноват, заработался - конечно экстендит)

Answer (score 2):

> Да, тут он пустой. Но дальше, в наследниках у меня тоже есть поля campaignsPath. И они там не пустые.

[@Stas0n](/users/9148/stas0n), т.е. вы зачем-то переопределяете поле `campaignsPath` в наследнике? Тогда, разумеется, родительский класс никогда не узнает, то вы туда положили. Он только в свои поля заглядывать умеет.

Я же предлагал не переопредлять, а передавать в конструктор родителя.

Ну или сделайте поле `campaignsPath` не `private`, а `protected`. Хотя вариант с конструктором красивее.

Comment: Уже исправил. Передаю campaignsPath конструктор.
Спасибо!